# FFMPEG : Two processes with a single action

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to complete the command with 2 different source files in one operation, is that possible?

my codes :

```
ffmpeg  -i 1.mp4  -i 1.png  -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.2*alpha(X,Y)'[zork];    [0:v][zork]overlay"  -vcodec libx264 myresult.mp4
ffmpeg  -y -i myresult.mp4  -i 2.png  -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'[zork];    [0:v][zork]overlay"  -vcodec libx264 1.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.png -i 2.png -filter_complex "[1:v]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.2*alpha(X,Y)'[zork1];[0:v][zork1]overlay[bg];[2]format=argb,geq=r='r(X,Y)':a='0.3*alpha(X,Y)'[zork2];[bg][zork2]overlay" -vcodec libx264 myresult.mp4
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!! @llogan So how can we handle commands that perform other operations but have the same input with a single output? For example, I have a command where I both muted the sound and added another music. I also want to add a logo to it. Is this possible with a single output? My commands are ready, by the way. I just want to get it done in one go.

Comment: @RewossKy Yes, it is possible. You should ask a new question (preferably at [su] so it doesn't get closed for being off-topic here as it is not a question specifically about programming).